# There is no output

Tags: python, xml

Hey guys here is my Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib

#asking for shopify link
print("What is the Web Adress of the product? e.g.:(Please with https:// infront)")

#getting shopify link
link = input()
print(link)
url = link +'.xml'
print(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
#asking for output
print("Do you want the output in Discord Embed (1) or just normal the links (2)?")

#getting output info
output = input()
print(output)

#parsing
root = ET.fromstring(response)

for sizecat in root.findall('variant'):
    id = sizecat.find('id').text
    shoe_size = sizecat.find('option1').text

    print(id, shoe_size)
```

But I dont get any output. No error nothing. Why?
I want to get in all the variant the id and the option1

Comment: That means `root.findall('variant')` isn't finding anything.

Comment: BTW, normally the prompt is the argument to `input()`, not a separate `print()` call.

Comment: I know but I want to see the output.

Comment: You can't see the output if there's nothing to see.

Comment: and why can see it when i open the website manuly?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's added dynamically by JavaScript. Do you see it when you use `View Source` on the website?

Comment: No when I go on the website e.g. https://anything.her/good.xml

Comment: `urllib` doesn't execute JavaScript, it just gets the HTML source code. You need to use something like Selenium Webdriver to emulate a browser.

Comment: When I print the root thats my output: <Element 'hash' at 0x000001449FC2AEA0>